# Load XSD schema model in C++

Tags: c++, xsd

Is there a C++ library I use to load the XSD schema model?

The goal is to load the actual XSD schema model (eventually from multiple files) in a way that I can then inspect the model elements (i.e., types, cardinality, attributes, even comments if possible). I don't want to use it for XML content but to manipulate/inspect the actual model.

I know that in Java it can be done, for example, with Xerces2 (http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/xml-schema.html), but I looked for something similar in C++ and could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the C++ implementation of EMF:
http://modeling-languages.com/emf4cpp-c-implementation-emf/

Then you could use the EMF XSD model:
http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd

The EMF XSD model is very well engineered, so the only question is around the maturity of the C++ port of EMF.